# Notepad++ Replace Integer Expression

Tags: notepad++

i am using notepad++ but i cant do this

from :

00000000000992 20160316030260000059 
 
00000000000992 20160316030260000060
 
00000000000992 20161014030140000073

to :

"00000000000992","20160316030260000059" 
 
"00000000000992","20160316030260000060" 
 
"00000000000992","20161014030140000073"

Comment: Do you have only two numbers per line or it can be more? Is the count of numbers the same in each line?

Comment: How can you not do this? Replace the space and replace `\r\n` (Extended Replace) with what's on the start and end of the line.

Comment: each line have 2 number only. im trying one hour.

Answer (score 0):

go to find and replace, select search mode to "Regular Expression", then replace following:

`(^|$)` to `"`

`[0-9][^0-9][0-9]` to `","`

You're done.

Comment: this answer does not work. i can try more situation . can u try another solution?

Comment: updated answer, should work as well. Check that you selected regular expression in search mode.